# How can i debug a python exe which is created by using pyinstaller?

Tags: python, windows, debugging, pyinstaller, executable

I have a python exe on windows 10 which has been created by pyinstaller.
How can i debug this python exe ?

i am not finding any help to debug python executable created by pyinstaller.
I know how to debug python code using source code.

I am looking for help either in terms of any link which i can go through to know how to debug python exe on windows created from pyinstaller.

Answer (score 0):

- Go to [this link](https://github.com/extremecoders-re/pyinstxtractor)
- Download the archive: pyinstxtractor-master.zip
- File:    pyinstxtractor.py unpack to the directory of the executable
  file.
- In    the address bar of the window (the folder of the executable
  file), enter the cmd command, press enter.
- In the console, enter the command:

```
python pyinstxtractor.py name.exe
```